# make another dictionary from dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I got a dictionary like this 
which has certain code for key and string for value

```
d={'A00': 'Cho', 'A00.0': 01,', 'A00.1': ' eltor'}
```

I was trying to make another dictionary from d something looks like:

```
d2={'A00.0':'C', 'A00.1':'h', 'A00.2':'o', 'A00.0.0':'0', 'A00.0.1':'1', 'A00.1.0':' ','A00.1.1':'e' and so on....}
```

which has code with index of character in string as key and character as value:

for do this I tried something like this
I made separated list of key and value

```
k =[~~~]
v= [~~~]
len_v = [] #length of each element in list v

for i in range(len(k)):
    for x in v:
        len_V.append((len(x)))
for code in k:
    for i in len_V:
        numb = 0
        while numb < i:
            print(code+'.'+str(numb))
            numb += 1
```

,but I failed how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, a `dict` comprehension

```
{k+'.'+str(i): v[i] for k, v in d.items() for i in range(len(v))}
```

Comment: This one work more properly thank you! trying to find why is the other answer doesn't work on some strings.

Comment: @goldenasian My solution's original use of `zip` was misguided and since fixed, but by all means keep this nice answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, a dictionary comprehension can do it in one line:

```
d = {'A00': 'Cho', 'A00.0': '01', 'A00.1': ' eltor'}
d2 = {k+'.'+str(i) : y for k,v in d.items() for i,y in enumerate(v)}
```

Then `d2` is:

```
{'A00.0': 'C', 'A00.1': 'h', 'A00.2': 'o', 'A00.0.0': '0', 'A00.0.1': '1', 'A00.1.0': ' ', 'A00.1.1': 'e', 'A00.1.2': 'l', 'A00.1.3': 't', 'A00.1.4': 'o', 'A00.1.5': 'r'}
```